# How to increase the spacing between two rows in a four-subfigure plot using Quarto's custom layout?

Tags: latex, pandoc, jupyter-lab, quarto, xetex

How can I increase the spacing between two rows in a four-subfigure plot using Quarto custom layout? I'm using Jupyter-lab for coding and Quarto to render pdf. And I have a four-subfigure plot like the one below (modified from the example in https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html):

```
#| label: fig-charts
#| fig-cap: Charts
#| fig-subcap: 
#|   - "First"
#|   - "Second"
#|   - "Third"
#|   - "Fourth"
#| layout-ncol: 2
#| layout: [[45,-10, 45], [45,-10, 45]]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.show()
```

I know by adding a negative number (-10) I can increase the horizontal spacing between two subfigures in the same row. But how can I increase the vertical spacing between two rows? I.e. the spacing between the first two and the last two figures? Thanks!

---

**Edit: Problem solved.**
See below @shafee's comment! So I shouldn't have put `layout-ncol` and `layout:` together.

Comment: Try `layout: [[45,-10, 45], [-10], [45,-10, 45]]`

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, actually the whole `layout: [[45,-10, 45], [45,-10, 45]]` formatting doesn't work, don't know why...

Comment: Do not use `layout-ncol`,  `layout` together. Remove the `layout-ncol: 2` and try `layout: [[45,-10, 45], [-10], [45,-10, 45]]` again.